# How to specify the url connection string to a Linked Server?

Tags: java, sql-server-2012, oledb, linked-server

I am trying to connect from a Java application to a Linked Server I created with MSSQL Server (called OLEDBSOURCE below). Can someone please help me get the connection string / url right?

```
db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://myipaddress:1433;databaseName=OLEDBSOURCE;
```

Below is a screenshot of SQL Server Management Studio. You can see where the Linked Servers section is, it's different than the databases... so how does the connection url need to be?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a non-default instance name? You might also need to append the username and password.

Comment: It's the default. I should also mention that I can connect just fine to my SQL databases under this same instance with this connection string.

Comment: Is your `OLEDBSOURCE` linked to another SQL Server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it helps anyone else:

The URL string itself was the same, minus the database name: db.url=jdbc:sqlserver://:1433;

For the query string however, I had to use OPENQUERY format:

```
            createSQLQuery("SELECT value "
                    + "FROM OPENQUERY(OLEDBSOURCE,'SELECT value "
                    + "FROM tablename ORDER BY value')")
```